# Page loosing global var values on page referesh / Browser reload

Tags: angular

My page works fine when invoked from a menu....Global variables loaded on ngOnInit is used to populate country list into select control and this works fine. However observed that when i reload the page thru browser refresh, global values goes empty, hence dropdown is also empty.
Service fetching country list :

```
@Injectable()
export class Globals {
    constructor( 
    public _countryService:CountryService,  )   {  } 
    public countryMaster = this.getscanCountries();
public getscanCountries(): Countrymaster {
    this._countryService.getCountryDetails().subscribe(
        data=> {this.countryDetails = data;
           // console.log('superset data-->',this.countryDetails);
            var  res = {                
                countryObj: this.countryDetails.map(function(c) {
                    var countryName = c.Country_Name.split(",")[0]; // token before first occurence of ','
                    return {
                      continent_code: c.Continent_Code,
                      continent_name:c.Continent_Name,
                      alpha2_Country_Code: c.Two_Letter_Country_Code,
                      Country_Name:countryName}
            }                )
             }
      //  console.log('global data 1-->',res);
        this.countryMaster =  res["countryObj"];
        console.log('global data --Country-->',this.countryMaster );
        return this.countryMaster;        
    }    
    );  
    return this.countryMaster;
}
}
```

Countries are loaded on module initialization..My component within this module access this global variable on ngOnInit.

```
constructor( private _reportersService :ReportersService,
private router: Router, private globals : Globals) {

 this.scanCountries = this.globals.countryMaster;
```

}
  ngOnInit() {

```
this.browserRefresh = browserRefresh;
console.log('browserRefresh in component', this.browserRefresh )  
console.log('ngOnInit',  this.scanCountries)
 }
```

Above works fine except browser refresh..

Console messages on page referesh is as follows:
[image]

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: that's the intended behavior, the question doesn't make sense

Comment: Sorry, unable to understand your point. Normal page load is able to access global var value correctly..whereas during browser reload is loosing it....any suggestion on addressing this issue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use localStorage or sessionStorage. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You also can implement decorator to make it easy in your service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LocalService {

  constructor(){}

    set(identifier:string, value:any){
        localStorage.setItem(identifier, JSON.stringify(value));
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(identifier));
    }

    get(identifier:string){
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(identifier));
    }

    remove(identifier:string){
        localStorage.removeItem(identifier);
    }
}


export function Local(identifier:string){
    return function (target: any, key: string){

        // property getter
        let getter = function(){
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(identifier));
        };

        // property setter
        let setter = function(newVal){
            let guardName:string = '__-' + key + '-_can_be_overriden_localStorage'; 
            if((typeof JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(identifier)) === 'undefined') || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(identifier)) == null){
        localStorage.setItem(identifier, JSON.stringify(newVal));
            } else if ( this[guardName]){
                localStorage.setItem(identifier, JSON.stringify(newVal));
      }

            this[guardName] = true;
        };

        // Delete property.
        if (delete target[key]){

            // Create new property with getter and setter
            Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
                get: getter,
                set: setter,
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
@Component({...}) class className implements ngOnInit{
    ...
    @Local('storageIdentifier') variable:string = 'default value.';
    constructor(){...}
    ngOnInit(){
      //change value in storage
      this.variable = 'some other value';
    }
    ...
}
```

Should be work for you like other decorators (Output Input ViewChild...)

Comment: Yes...able to solve this using local storage. Have used  localStorage.setItem('scanCountries',JSON.stringify(this._globals.scanCountries)); on Module initialization and access this data from various components using JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scanNullValues'));...Works fine as of now...btw, why would I implement get/set/move etc in my code?...any shortcomings on my code?...thanks for advising the right direction...Will accept the solution.

Comment: @NewbieAngular you don't have to create an extra layer like I did. My applications complexity require to do things like this. If in the future I want to create a side effect when I set, get, remove the localStorage items, I will not need to rewire every calls. For example if tomorrow I need to log everything that is being saved into the storage, then I just extend the set function with a logger. I wont need to rewrite every file where I used the set; just at one single core place. +Extends Local decorator functionality. From the nature of ts decorators you cant give parameter like 'string'+var